# If statement in .aspx page

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to include an If statement in some Javascript on my .aspx page.

I declare FinishedPacking at the beginning of the page as False. Then when a user clicks the orderSubmit button, the if Statement evaluates if the value is indeed false, if so, display an alert. So far the if statement does not work. If I use just the alert with no if statement it displays the alert:

```
    var FinishedPacking = false;

    $("#orderSubmit").click(function (e) {
       if (FinishedPacking = false) {
       alert("The order is not finished.")
       }
       ClearScreen();
       GetOrder();
    }):
```

As stated if I do not include the if statement, the alert works when I click the order button. Not sure why this simple If statement is not being picked up.

Comment: It should be `Finishedpacking == false` in the `if`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the double-equals

`if (FinishedPacking = false)`

should be

`if (FinishedPacking == false)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var FinishedPacking = false;

$("#orderSubmit").click(function (e) {
   if (FinishedPacking == false) {
   alert("The order is not finished.")
   }
   ClearScreen();
   GetOrder();
}):
```

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 ='s signs

```
if (FinishedPacking == false) {
```

You are trying to ASSIGN false to the variable FinishedPacking inside your condition (which is wrong) you want to COMPARE the values.